# Gnuplot gives weird error when plotting scaled data ("x range is invalid")

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a very simple data plot from an experiment we're running at my work. Essentially, I only need to plot y vs. x from a tab-separated data file which looks like this:

> 468.822   5.76025 2.3631  3   271.91676   60.13701 
>   896.187   5.52183 1.11077 2   519.78846   57.6479052 
>   731.708   6.38751 0.697295    1   424.39064   66.6856044

[and about 2000 more lines like this]

The first two columns are my x and y values.
Now, this is a data taken from a video, so it's represented in pixels, but we need to convert it to the right units (μm and μm/sec instead of pixels, and pixels/frame). For this reason, I plot the data with the following line:

```
plot 'datafile.data' u 1*xScale:2*yScale pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red" title "[some title]"
```

I get an error saying:

> plot 'datafile.data' u 1*xScale:2*yScale pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red" title "[some title]" 
>   ^ 
>   "datafile.data", line 9: x range is invalid

(with the ^ sign pointing at the end of the above line)

I tried to scale the data itself (these are columns 5 and 6), but it gives the same error.

Anyone has any idea to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you have uses the result of the arithmetic expression `1*xScale` as column number, and same for the second expression. What you want is

```
plot 'datafile.data' u ($1*xScale):($2*yScale) pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red" title "[some title]"
```